# Looping through columns

Tags: shell-script, csv

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
first_name,surname,email,
first_name2,surname2,email2,
....3,..
....4,...
```

The number of rows in each column are the same.

I want to run a command that iterates through each column and fetches the value from each column and replaces it in the command.

For example,

```
for each_row;
 do [command foo{first_name} .... bar{surname}.... sth_else{email}]; 
done
```

I was thinking of doing something like

```
for i in `awk -F, '{print  $1}' my_file.csv`; do
  some command with i`;
done
```

However, this only allows me to run my command with the values from field 1. How do I go about running my command such that it allows me to get values from each column with each iteration?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your CSV is in a "simple CSV" format, where no field has embedded commas or newlines (which are allowed in generic CSV files, with properly quoted fields), you may read the fields directly with `read`:

```bsh
while IFS=, read -r name familyname address; do
    printf 'Got "%s", "%s", and "%s"\n' "$name" "$familyname" "$address"
done <file.csv
```

The `read` utility will split each line into fields on the values in `$IFS`, and we make sure that this variable contains a comma when calling `read`. The first two comma-delimited fields will end up in the variables `name` and `familyname`, while *the rest of the line* will end up in the variable `address`.  If each line ends in an unwanted comma (as in the question), then read a dummy variable on each line (add `dummy` after `address` as a separate variable with `read`), or adjust the value of `address` with `address=${address%,}` inside the loop to chop the trailing comma off.

We use `-r` with `read` to read any backslashes in the data correctly.

If the CSV file has a header line that you need to skip,

```bsh
sed 1d file.csv |
while IFS=, read -r name familyname address; do
    printf 'Got "%s", "%s", and "%s"\n' "$name" "$familyname" "$address"
done
```

In place of the `sed` command (which deletes the first line of input and passes all other lines on), you may use `tail -n +2`, which does the same thing.

Comment: Nice taking into account the header.

Comment: The only problem I see with this approach is that if there are more columns they have to be added to the while loop, but of course it's not the case of OP's sample.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity If you have more columns _that you want to access individually_, yes. In `bash`, you could use `mapfile` instead and slurp each line into an array, and then pick and choose the fields based on their indexes, or you may pre-process the data with `cut` to pick out the fields that your want for the `while` loop.  I'm not adding this to the answer as it wasn't part of the question.

Comment: Yes, just an observation. Also it's not clear what does OP refers as *"command"*, which I took as *any* command in my answer, but you interpret, I think rightly, that is just printing the result with added strings.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Yeah, `printf` is really just "any command", which I give the fields that I read from the data to. This seemed to fit the invented syntax of the question.

Comment: Also note that Bash `read -a myArray` will read a variable number of fields into an array, so you can find the number of columns, iterate over them, and avoid needing to have a lot of specific names for the fields.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes, and I would have added something like that if the question had indicated that there was an indefinite number of fields per record.

Comment: @they  The question starts with "Looping" and ends with "iteration". Others may find this question in the future with those keywords, and I always prefer a generic solution over a specific one: "Two or more, use a `for`".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can use `xargs`, for example:

```bsh
$ cat file | sed 's/,$//' | xargs -d, -I {} echo {} | sed 's/a/@/'
first_n@me
sur n@me
em@il
first_n@me2
sur n@me2
em@il2
```

- `sed 's/,$//'` will remove the last comma `,`
- `xargs -d, -I {}`: will use comma `-d,` as the delimiter of the arguments, `-I {}` will allow us to pass the arguments to the piped `echo` and `sed`.

To avoid parsing the header [see @they's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/673039/338177).

---

Note: I changed the input a little adding spaces.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you could do a system call like this:

```
awk -F',' '{system("<command> "$1" "$2" "$3)}' file
```

It might be needed to quote the variables passed to the shell, e.g. with surnames that consist of two, space-separated elements - this also depends on how your command understands space-separated items. In that case use:

```
awk -F',' '{system("<command> \""$1"\" \""$2"\" \""$3"\"")}'
```

Comment: You probably need to quote the values for the shell that `system()` spawns.

Comment: @they fair point